# Large capacitor at the output of high-side switch

Tags: capacitor

I am looking at using DIODES' [AP2411](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP24x1.pdf) high-side switch. Their typical app circuit shows a 120 μF capacitor at the output. Is that value too high? I am going to power on and off an ESP8622 IC that can sink up to 300 mA.

[image: AP2411]

Comment: I setup the circuit above on a solderless test board and connected the output to 20 ohm resistor to ground.  Input voltage is 3.3V from a lab power supply. The output voltage i get is about 2.8V. Is that normal to lose almost 0.5V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chip is designed for switching USB power and that requires 120uF capacitance. So it is not too high, the chip can handle it, as shown in the manufacturer datasheet.

Comment: after reading article recommended by @TonyStewartEE75 - "...VBUS power lines must be bypassed with no less than 120μF"  i see what you meant.   understood now. thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is better to search for the reason why , than assume the OEM design is wrong for this mass production part.   (esp. if you are a rookie , no offense)

https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/power_delivery_motherboards.pdf?msclkid=00caf2e1a86b11ec963331edf988a8f2

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers, I would like to add, that you should look on the needs and behavior of your own design.
You can experiment with different capacitor types and capacities, while checking each one with the oscilloscope to have a look on the voltage ripple and behavior, mainly by placing the oscilloscope probes on that capacitor, using proper probing techniques for high frequencies:

[image: probing technique]

Image source: https://www.electronicspecifier.com/products/power/oscilloscope-probing-techniques-for-measuring-power-supply-ripple

And check how it startups, how it shuts down and how it behaves under load and under no load.